# Visual Basic Confusion

Tags: vb.net

I have been required to create a program that asks me to find the maximum value of one particular array. I am using multiple forms in this project and have used a user-defined data type and created multiple array under it. There is a first form that is related to this, which defines my defined data type is gStudentRecord and the arrays that define it are last name, Id, and GPA. This second form is where I write all of the code to display what I want. My question is how to get the Max GPA out of that array. I'm sorry if this isn't in very good format, this is the first time I've used Stackoverflow

```
Public Class frmSecond

  Private Sub frmSecond_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Ctr As Integer
    Dim Line As String

    lstDisplay.Items.Clear()

    lstDisplay.Items.Add("Name".PadRight(25) & "ID".PadRight(16) & "GPA".PadRight(20) & "Out of state".PadRight(10))
    For Ctr = 0 To gIndex Step 1
        Line = gCourseRoster(Ctr).LastName.PadRight(20) & gCourseRoster(Ctr).ID.PadRight(15) & gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA.ToString.PadRight(15) & gCourseRoster(Ctr).OutOfState.ToString().PadLeft(5)
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(Line)
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnStats_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStats.Click
    Dim Ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim Average As Double
    Dim Sum As Double
    Dim Found As Boolean = False
    Dim Pass As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer

    lstDisplay.Items.Clear()

    **For Ctr = 0 To gIndex Step 1
        If gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA > gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA Then

            lstDisplay.Items.Add(gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA)
        End If
    Next**

    Average = gComputeAverage(Sum)

    lstDisplay.Items.Add("Number of Students: " & gNumberOfStudents)
    lstDisplay.Items.Add("Average: " & Average)

  End Sub
  Private Function gComputeAverage(Sum As Double) As Double
    Dim Ctr As Integer
    Dim Average As Double

    For Ctr = 0 To gIndex Step 1
        Sum = Sum + gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA
    Next

    Average = Sum / gNumberOfStudents
    Return Average
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Use a `List(Of gCourseRoster)` instead of an array - it is a type specific collection.

Comment: `gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA > gCourseRoster(Ctr).GPA` will always be false, because the comparison has the same two things on either side of the inequality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lambda expression to tease it out. The `Cast` part is converting from the `gCourseRoster` to a collection of `Double` by supplying the `GPA` to the `Select` statement.

```
Dim gList As New List(Of gCourseRoster)
gList.Add(New gCourseRoster With {.id = 1, .name = "Bob", .GPA = 3.9})
gList.Add(New gCourseRoster With {.id = 2, .name = "Sarah", .GPA = 3.2})
gList.Add(New gCourseRoster With {.id = 3, .name = "Frank", .GPA = 3.1})
Dim maxGPA = gList.Cast(Of gCourseRoster).Select(Function(c) c.GPA).ToList.Max
MessageBox.Show(maxGPA.ToString)

Output: 3.9
```